# DataTable.ImportRow is not adding rows

Tags: c#, datatable

I'm trying to make a DataTable and then add a couple rows to it.  Here's my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data;


namespace thisNamespace
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt=new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("XYZID");
            DataRow dr=dt.NewRow();
            dr["XYZID"]=123;
            dt.ImportRow(dr);
            dr["XYZID"] = 604303;
            dt.ImportRow(dr);

        }
    }
}
```

When I step through the program, `dr` is successfully initialized and populated with values, but then after `ImportRow(dr)`, the count of rows in `dt` is still 0.  I feel like I must be missing something obvious.  What's going wrong here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this code:

`dt.Rows.Add(dr)`

Comment: But why? `ImportRow` sounds like it should do that.

Comment: ImportRow takes a DataRow that already belongs to another DataTable's Rows collection, and brings it into another DataTable.

Comment: It does not work if the row belongs to another table

Comment: it apparently doesn't work if it belongs to the SAME table either.  I created one using .NewRow() and populated it then was unable to import it.

Answer (score 11):

If the row is detached (as it is when it is first created) ImportRows fails silently (no exception) - to be able to import rows you have to Add it into the table. Afterwards you can import it into other tables.

Answer (score 1):

Its May Help you

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("Dosage", typeof(int));
    table.Columns.Add("Drug", typeof(string));
    table.Columns.Add("Patient", typeof(string));
    table.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));

    //
    // Here we add five DataRows.
    //
    table.Rows.Add(25, "Indocin", "David", DateTime.Now);
    table.Rows.Add(50, "Enebrel", "Sam", DateTime.Now);
    table.Rows.Add(10, "Hydralazine", "Christoff", DateTime.Now);
    table.Rows.Add(21, "Combivent", "Janet", DateTime.Now);
    table.Rows.Add(100, "Dilantin", "Melanie", DateTime.Now);
```

Answer (score 1):

You first need to add the row:

```
 dt.Rows.Add(dr);
```

Then you must call below method to commit it:

```
 dt.AcceptChanges();
```

Comment: I'm upvoting this but i didn't have to run acceptchanges.  The data was in the table after the .add.